fgets and Segmentation Fault
I got this function:
#define DIGITS_MAXIMUM_NUMBER 10

int* read_from_file(const char* file_name)
{
        int limit = 101;
        int *values = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);
        FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
        char string_value[DIGITS_MAXIMUM_NUMBER];
        int i = 1;

        while(fgets(string_value, DIGITS_MAXIMUM_NUMBER, fp) != NULL)
        {
                if (i >= limit) {
                        limit += 100;
                        values = realloc(values, limit);
                }

                values[i] = atoi(string_value);
                i++;
                if ( i >= 106 )
                        printf("%d\n", i);
        }

        values[0] = i;

        if (i != limit)
                values = realloc(values, i);

        fclose(fp);
        return values;
}


I get Segmentation fault at the 106th iteration, so it means that the loop works, but at that certain iteration, when fgets is executed, Segmentation fault is raised.
If anybody knows why or have at least an opinion, it would be great to share, thanks.

Are you properly freeing the returned pointer in the calling function?

values = realloc(values, limit); ==> values = realloc(values, sizeof *values * limit); and similarly a few lines below

Always check if fopen was successful or not.

@pmg You could post that as the answer to the question.

Suggestion: unsigned read_from_file(int **dst, const char *file_name); ... return the number of values directly and put the values in the pointer passed in. No more need for a special values[0] :-)

Checking if your memory allocation returnd NULL would also be a good idea.

char string_value[DIGITS_MAXIMUM_NUMBER]; is too small to save "-2147483648\n" as a string.  Suggest char string_value[DIGITS_MAXIMUM_NUMBER + 3]; ...          while(fgets(string_value, sizeof string_value, fp) != NULL).

Immediate solution:
// values = realloc(values, limit);
values = realloc(values, sizeof *values * limit);

There's a lot more you can improve though!

Wow, I got to say, I'm impressed.
I always have thought to know the C language very well, but this time I guess I have learned that I have a lot to learn.
